# Flutter Provider Failed assertion: line 156

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm trying implement some Google ads thanks AdMob and I'm using Provider plugin.
When I'm using provider.value my code isn't working.
I really dont understand why. Please help.

This is my code:

```
import 'package:distance_meter/ad_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'pages/loading_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final initFuture = MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  final adState = AdState(initFuture);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  runApp(
    Provider.value(
      value: (context, child) => MaterialApp(home: Loading())
    )
  );
}
```

And this is that error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Provider<(dynamic, dynamic) => MaterialApp>(value: Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => MaterialApp, dirty):
Provider<(dynamic, dynamic) => MaterialApp> used outside of MultiProvider must specify a child
'package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart':
Failed assertion: line 156 pos 7: 'builder != null || child != null'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Provider<(dynamic, dynamic) => MaterialApp> file:///D:/MyProjects-active/distance-meter/lib/main.dart:18:14
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      InheritedProvider.buildWithChild (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:156:7)
#3      SingleChildStatelessWidget.build (package:nested/nested.dart:259:41)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4569:28)
#5      SingleChildStatelessElement.build (package:nested/nested.dart:279:18)
#6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
...
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check out the correct way to use Provider.value()

That constructor expects a value (the Provider instance you want to make available to its widget sub-tree, previously instantiated), and a builder function (what you are actually building beneath the provider)

You syntax should be

```
final _instanceOfYourProvider = YourProvider();

Provider<YourProvider>.value(
    value: _instanceOfYourProvider,
    builder: (context, child) => MaterialApp(home: Loading()),
);
```

In any case, be careful when instantiating your Provider that far up your widget tree. It is always best to instantiate it just above the lowest level that will work for your use case. (e.g. if you just need it for one screen, instantiate it just above that screen)

Comment: so, is this right ? `void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final initFuture = MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  final adState = AdState(initFuture);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  final _instanceOfYourProvider = Provider();

  runApp(


  Provider<Provider>.value(
    value: _instanceOfYourProvider,
    builder: (context, child) => MaterialApp(home: Loading()),
  )
  );
}` Because my app are not loading. It's just white background.

Comment: is your Provider class named "Provider"?? if not, where I put "YourProvider" you should replace it with you Provider's class name